# Failure authenticating with NTLM <any realm>@dev-d

Tags: java, soap, ntlm

We are trying to invoke a webservice on Windows server which needs NTLM authentication. We invoked the same using Soap ui and the process is successful.
Java class is created for this and when we try to run the service it gives below error.

```
INFO: Failure authenticating with NTLM <any realm>@dev-dmsdca01:80
POST METHOD
Method Failed :HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Is there any mechanism to see the logs which the target server has.

Comment: Is the webservice running on Java ? If so, try adding this property to your startup : -Dntlm.debug and hopefully we have more info for debugging.

Comment: Hey Eugene. Could you let me know where to add this?

Comment: If your Tomcat is started with a Windows service, you need to edit that service. It is in the registry, have a look here : https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?21926,How+to+change+Windows+Registry+values+for+Tomcat,